# Ghost custom Bootstrap HTML elements in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less

In the footer of my ASP.NET MVC website, I am returning a partial view containing a "photo feed" of my latest artwork. The view uses styled `<ul>` and `<li>` tags to organize the images. The stylings are pulled from the [ReStart Bootstrap theme](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0NPLR53). Below is the demo content for the view:

[image]

Here is the markup contained within the partial view that is producing the content above:

```
<div class="footer_teaser col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="latest-flickr-images">
<h3 style="color:#ffffff">Recent photography</h3>
<ul>

</ul>
<p>All photos © by <a href="https://www.snobbyphotographer.net" style="color:#ffffff"><strong>Kanapolis</strong></a>.</p>
```

Notice anything interesting? Correct, I have removed the `<li>`tags and content links from the markup, yet the demo content persists in debug. Removing the `<ul>` tags gets rid of them. In Restart's root `style.css` file and the pre-compiled `style.less`, I can see the selector is named `#latest-flickr-images ul`. However, I can't find any script files in my project directory that are targeting this particular `<ul>` element. I am not super familiar with CSS or preprocessors like LESS and how they interact with jQuery. What am I missing here?

Comment: I suppose it's not CSS *creating* these elements (simply because CSS can't do this), but some script. So it has very few to do with CSS and therefor Less. Learn what scripts are used in the template you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the undesired behavior by locating the jQuery script in the theme's main scripts template file that was pointing to the `<ul>` and commented it out:

```
    ////Flickr feed snippet by css-tricks.com              
//    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=37321137@N03&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
//               var target = "#latest-flickr-images ul"; // Where is it going?
//               for (i = 0; i <= 9; i = i + 1) { // Loop through the 10 most recent, [0-9]
//                       var pic = data.items[i];
//                       var liNumber = i + 1; // Add class to each LI (1-12)
//                       jQuery(target).append("<li class='flickr-image no-" + liNumber + "'><a rel='prettyPhoto' title='" + pic.title + "' href='" + pic.link + "'><img src='" + pic.media.m + "' /></a></li>");
//               }
//    });
```